# Starting & Stopping a sound (Code provided) iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avplayer

I have a single sound and it plays via http through my server. However it successfully plays though my server but the sound doesn't seem to stop. I've tried to code it to stop, but I'm having no luck. Help appreciated

```
- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender; {
    if (ButtonAlReadyClicked == 1) 
    {
        ButtonAlReadyClicked = 2;

        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"m2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else if (ButtonAlReadyClicked == 2) 
    {
        ButtonAlReadyClicked = 1;

        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"m1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }  
    if (player && player.playing) {
        [player stop];
        [player release];
        player = nil;
        return;
    }    

    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/hi.mp3"]] retain];

    [player play];

}
```

The error which I get is ' error: use of undeclared identifier 'player' [3]

Answer (score 0):

The `if (player …` line always returns false because you have `player` as a local variable, not an instance ivar. Add a `player` ivar to your `.h` file, then save the one you init to it, not to a local player.

Comment: I get error ' error: Semantic Issue: Property 'playing' not found on object of type 'AVPlayer *'
'

Comment: That is because AVPlayer does not have a playing property. Check the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable in your .h file called player and the instantiate player upon click of the button. The reason that you are getting the error is because the player variable is declared after you try and access the variable and it's property.

```
- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender {
    if (player == nil) {
        player = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/hi.mp3"]] retain];
        [player play];
        ButtonAlReadyClicked = 1;
        [self oneSound:sender];
        return;
    }
    if (ButtonAlReadyClicked == 1) {
        ButtonAlReadyClicked = 2;
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"m2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if (ButtonAlReadyClicked == 2) 
    {
        ButtonAlReadyClicked = 1;
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"m1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }  
    if (player && player.playing) {
        [player stop];
        [player release];
        player = nil;
        return;
    }    

}
```

Comment: This is still incorrect the way you have it. It is a local player object, not an instance variable

Comment: I can confirm that didn't work, appreciate trying to help though!

Comment: I never said that would work, I appreciate that you tried it, but it is there as an example of something you could do. I presume it is something todo with `ButtonAlReadyClicked`. Edit-- Remove the `AVPlayer * player` I left that in by accident. @coneybeare

Comment: Does the ivar player need to be in the .h?